# ORDER BY is breaking my complex QUERY

Tags: php, mysql

I have a complex query that breaks when I try to add `"ORDER BY b.allowed"` - where can I add this, and why is it breaking the query?

```
$listpage = mysql_query(
"SELECT 
    LEFT(a.post_content, 80) AS excerpt, a.id, 
    a.post_title, a.guid,
    MAX(CASE WHEN b.meta_key = 'allowed' THEN b.meta_value END) allowed,
    MAX(CASE WHEN b.meta_key = 'amenities' THEN b.meta_value END) amenities,
    MAX(CASE WHEN b.meta_key = 'trail-type' THEN b.meta_value END) trailtype,
    MAX(CASE WHEN b.meta_key = 'miles' THEN b.meta_value END) miles,
    MAX(CASE WHEN b.meta_key = '_pronamic_google_maps_latitude' 
        THEN b.meta_value END) weatherlat,
    MAX(CASE WHEN b.meta_key = '_pronamic_google_maps_longitude' 
        THEN b.meta_value END) weatherlon
 FROM 
    wp_posts a
    LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta b ON a.id = b.post_id
 WHERE 
    a.id IN (SELECT object_id AS id FROM wp_term_relationships 
       WHERE term_taxonomy_id = ". $mycatid .") 
 group by b.post_id");
```

Comment: The server knows, and it's telling you by returning an error message. What is it?

Comment: Place the order by inmediatly after the group by, sorry

Comment: The problem is: `b.allowed` is not a column, that's it.

Comment: Agree with @Rafa, quick way to sort it. :) is use column index e.g. order by 4

Comment: So, it WAS the column name issue - correct - but the only error was "SYNTAX ERROR near..."  A bit cryptic, but I should have included that in the question.  Thanks, everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to add this after the *group by* clause:

```
ORDER BY 5
```

"5" means in this case, the fifth field (allowed).

I hope it helps you.